# Why does SSIS load my apostrophes incorrectly?

Tags: unicode, ssis, character-encoding

I have a text file which has field with the following data in it:

```
Australian Children’s Television Fo ;
```

When I load it to a sql server table it loads it as

```
Australian Childrenâ€™s Television Fo ;
```

Why is the apostrophe getting loaded as those special characters?

I've tried reading them in as unicode strings and using nvarchar as the datatype in the table. None of it works.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.

[image]

I took your text, pasted it into a new file and saved with what TextPad calls "Unicode" encoding (little endian) as there is also "Unicode (big endian)" option.  You can get the same effect in Visual Studio with a Save As of either Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001 or Unicode Codepage - 1200.

[image]

Using your hex editor of choice, open the file up. Here I'm using xvi32 because it's a lightweight, no frills tool

[image]

Those spaces there are good, that means it's really a unicode file.

My Connection Manager looks like

[image]

and my advanced column page is

[image]

The Biml to reproduce my package is trivial. Install [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) Add a new biml file to the IS project. Paste the following in there after adjusting the third line to point to the file you created as unicode. Save, right click and Generate SSIS package

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <FlatFileConnection FilePath="C:\ssisdata\so_29439216.txt" FileFormat="FFF" Name="FF_CM" />
    </Connections>
    <FileFormats>
        <FlatFileFormat Name="FFF" IsUnicode="true" FlatFileType="Delimited">
            <Columns>
                <Column Name="SourceRow" DataType="String" Length="50" Delimiter="CRLF" InputLength="50" />
            </Columns>
        </FlatFileFormat>
    </FileFormats>
    <Packages>
        <Package ConstraintMode="Linear" Name="so_29439216">
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT Source">
                    <Transformations>
                        <FlatFileSource ConnectionName="FF_CM" Name="FFS"></FlatFileSource>
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DFT Dataviewer anchor point"></DerivedColumns>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Comment: When I check on Unicode in my connection manager my data completely gets corrupted. And my code page is (65001)UTF-8. I did make the advanced option as WSTR. But my table is still getting populated with Australian Childrenâ€™s ; My input file btw is encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: If you replicate my steps, do you get a file that correctly parses? If it does, then it becomes a matter of refining your question to get to the variance. If you can't match what I show, then there's something wrong with your machine (doubtful but stranger things happen).